# Chrome Extension. Закрыть вкладку по таймеру

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, скрипт, extension

Подскажите пожалуйста новичку. Есть кнопка, по нажатию на неё происходит переход на страницу. Как закрыть эту страницу через N секунд, после перехода?

Или может есть другой способ решения моей задачи. Делаю "отправитель сообщения в whatsapp" из расширения. Для запуска ватсап используется ссылка, но после перехода в приложение, остается вкладка в браузере. Хотелось бы ее как то ликвидировать. Или запускать ватсап другим способом.

```
function prv() {    
    var word = document.getElementById("number").value;
word = parseInt(word);   
     chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone='+word, });
```

Comment: т.е при любом переходе(даже набрав путь к файлу в браузере) данная страница должна закрыться через N секунд ?

Comment: @Alexandr всё зависит от того, как Вы открываете эту ссылку. Можете показать?

Comment: @Alexandr добавил описание:)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете закрыть созданный таб методом API. Для этого вы должны получить ID данного таба, вот пример։

```
var newTabId = 0;
/*Открываем ссылку*/
chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone='+word, },function(tab){
    newTabId = tab.id;
});

/*Закрываем через сек.*/

setTimeout(function(){
 chrome.tabs.remove(newTabId ,function(tab){ });
},1000);
```

> UPD

Можно сразу сделать в колбеке самой `create`

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + word,
}, function (tab) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function () {});
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Логично таймер внутрь коллбэка запихнуть.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, конечно, просто это 'эхо' из практики, стараюсь показывать пример кода по разным блокам т.к бывали случаи, когда некоторые пользователи думали, что так может работать только в колбеке :) Добавлю  и короткий метод.

Comment: Хром за секунлду может даже не начать вкладку открывать в некоторых случаях. Размещение вызова вне коллбэка - в данном случае ошибка.

Comment: @Alexandr покажите ваш код, как внедрили мой пример?

Comment: @Alexandr   откройте консоль браузера и нажмите на вашу кнопку, новое окно открывается и не закрывается? нет ли в консоли каких то JS ошибок, внимательно проверьте.

Comment: @Arsen Ошибки присутствуют только когда переход происходит по ссылке выше. Если изменить ссылку на пустую страницу или любую другую, то ошибок нет, но вкладка так же не закрывается.  Я пробовал обоими вышими вариантами Не пойму в чем может быть причина. Может быть id страницы неизвестно в функции?

Comment: @Alexandr данный пример рабочий, у меня так несколько расширений без проблем работают, возможно у вас что то вызывает конфликт. На счёт ID, можете проверить и вызвать в колбеке `console.log(tab.id)` что показывает?